# Place quadratic roots into list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def quadratic_roots(a,b,c):
        if not (type(a)==int or type(a)==float) and (type(b)==int or type(b)==float)\
   and (type(c)==int or type(c)==float):
    print("Error. Must be numbers.")
    return None
equation=(b**2)-(4*a*c)
realRoots=[]
if equation<0:
    return realRoots
elif equation==0:
    x1=-b/(2*a)
    #realRoots.append(x)
    return [x1]
else:
    x1=(-b+((equation)^(1/2))/(2*a)
    x2=(-b-((equation)^(1/2))/(2*a)
    return realRoots.append(x1,x2)
```

I need to put my quadratic roots into a list but I keep getting syntax errors. How can i edit my code so that it will function properly?

Answer (score 1):

`append` only takes one argument and returns `None` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)):

```
return realRoots.append(x1,x2)  # cannot work

# Instead, either `append` one by one:
realRoots.append(x1)
realRoots.append(x2)
return realRoots

# or use 'extend':
realRoots.extend([x1, x2])
return realRoots

# or the simplest
return [x1, x2]
```

Btw, the 'power'-operator in Python is `**`, not `^`:

```
> 2**3
8

> 2^3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @schwobaseggl said, you have to change the power operator and the append syntax.
also notice that the append method doesn't  return any value (None by default)
so `return realRoots.append(x1)` adds `x1` to `realRoots` but returns `None`